# Stress test using only Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I love Selenium IDE; mainly because it enables me to automate many regression tests without me having to write any code at all!

Now, I want to do load testing on my website i.e execute the same quantum of testing activity concurrently with many browser windows putting load on the website to check if it holds integrity. I want to stick to the GUI (Selenium IDE) and still want to accomplish this.

I searched and found Selenium Grid can help me accomplish this, however, running Grid involves exporting test cases to Java TestNG WebDriver or something similar and then setting up test suites. This will definitely involve some complexity in terms of coding.

The question is can I avoid this and stick to Selenium IDE (the GUI) to perform this task?

*Many thanks in advance!*

Comment: short answer: not really. check out SoapUI and what it can do for you

Comment: Not just this, I also feel after reading up the documentation, that Selenium Grid isn't really mean for stress testing, rather distributing my test load.
However, I still don't want to give up on selenium for stress testing, and I am planning to use Grid on a headless browser (phantomJS) to reduce load on my RAM and still manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way (that i can think of) is running the same script on multiple computers at the same time. I would run the script as fast as you can without having it crash in normal circumstances. Grab a few volunteers and get everyone to click RUN at the same time.

Alternatively you could run multiple VM clients if you don't have access to multiple computers. Your internet connection may be the only barrier to entry with the VM method

Comment: I did try that and I 'd add it was productive to some extent (read some new bugs did come out). Thanks!
But it was still not the only thing I did; for wider audience, I used html-unit to stress test the core services of my website. That was helpful in bringing out some discrepancies too, but it involved some coding :3

Comment: I am yet to try this but I will be doing it shortly once i get all my test scripts up and running. Its good to know it did work to some extent :)